# Usage of word "annealing" to describe a slowly increasing probability

Tags: optimization, simulation, terminology

I have a kind of "soft" question, related to usage of the term "annealing". The actual annealing process in metallurgy involves heating and then slowly cooling a metal. In the optimization literature and in the simulated annealing algorithm, it is used for a slowly decreasing acceptance probability. In a recent paper I have submitted to a conference, I have used it as such:

> We route a sample $x$ in the split node $i$ into the $k$-th path, as long as $p_i(n_i=k|x) \geq \rho$, where $\rho$ is a threshold; starting with $0$ and annealed during the training. The experts gradually get focused on their partition, initially seeing data from other partitions and only focusing on their later in the training. The upper bound for $\rho$ is $1/K$, where $K$ is the number of child nodes of node $i$. This ensures at least one path is always activated.

Here, $p_i(n_i|x)$ is a discrete probability distribution, explicitly defined elsewhere in the paper. What I am actually doing here is to define a threshold $\rho$, starting from $0$ which is then gradually increased up to a maximum $1/K$, during an iterative training process (Gradient descent). 
I have already submitted the paper for review but I am now unsure whether this usage of "annealing" here describes what I am trying to tell, a process of slowly changing the value of a hyperparameter. Is it wrong to use the term "annealing" here?

Comment: Related, but maybe not the same, homotopy methods for equation solving and optimization https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/19501/TR-88-51.pdf?

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of the term "annealing" does not convey what you intend it to.

If you refer to the original simulated annealing paper by [Kirkpatrick et al](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/220/4598/671), you will see that the term "annealing" refers to the physical or simulated process of heating then cooling a metallic material.

Consider using a simple term like "increased/updated/varied during training".

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that your usage of the term is inappropriate - yes, double negative!

You are increasing the threshold thus making unlikely to take the path k, and freezing out some paths. That's not dissimilar to a term `annealing` in spirit as used in Monte Carlo simulation literature today.